# How accurate are interlinear texts, or linguistic glosses?

Tags: dictionary, interlinear-gloss

Here are 2 examples of interlinear texts:

- [Quran (Arabic)](https://corpus.quran.com/wordbyword.jsp)
- [Bible (Greek)](https://biblehub.com/bib/matthew/1.htm)

And [here](https://biblehub.com/greek/1097.htm) is a term `γινώσκω`, which is defined shortly as "to come to know, recognize, perceive", but in one word as "knew" in the Bible Greek link.

More deeply, it is defined as:

> ascertaining (1), aware (7), certainty (1), come to know (1), comprehend (1), felt (1), find (3), found (2), kept...a virgin* (1), knew (13), know (104), know how (1), knowing (3), known (25), knows (14), learn (1), learned (1), perceived (1), perceiving (2), put (1), realize (3), recognize (7), recognized (1), recognizing (1), sure (4), take notice (1), unaware* (2), understand (11), understood (6)

Or more precisely:

> properly, to know, especially through personal experience (first-hand acquaintance)

I have been thinking about cross-linguistic dictionaries lately, and to me there are 3 levels of a "definition" of a term:

1. **1 word definition** (from source to target language). Sometimes it's not possible to use just one word? (דִּישׂן = mountain goat, דִּימוֹנָה = a place in Judah, דָּחַק = to thrust, crowd, oppress). Use 2-3 words if necessary instead of 1.
2. **several 1 word definitions**. This is like the "More deeply" section above, which lists like 20 words to define the Greek work. Use 2-3 words if necessary instead of 1 for each.
3. **a prose definition**. A sentence written out to describe more subtly the meaning.

It appears that the linguistic glosses, like in that Greek Bible, are mostly 1-2 word "definitions". But how accurate are those definitions? Does it only give you a partial glimpse of the meaning? Is it sufficient, or at least does it serve as a good entry point for understanding?

Then "concise" dictionaries do #2 and list several meanings (Google search does this when translating from English to another language). Then research dictionaries (or people's life work dictionaries) have sometimes several sentences of definition, #3. The THLib Tibetan dictionary is like this.

Is it fair to say that these 3 layers can be used to effectively teach someone the meaning of a new term over time? Start with the basic 1-word to give a hint, which doesn't corrupt. Then after some time, go to many words to paint a blended view of the term, more subtle. Then only when necessary, dig into the details of the term with a prose definition.

My go to example currently is "dharma", mapped to "morality". Technically dharma is much more subtle and complex than just saying "morality", but morality gets you more than 50% of the way there to understanding, so it seems like an alright gloss.

I am trying to find ways of segmenting the task down, so you can have interlinear glosses of texts with minimal fluff, and yet have richer definitions when you dig down. But not sure if minimizing the definition to just 1 term is always possible, or if it's a problem which leads to bad understandings. If it's not a problem, then I would go ahead with creating an interlinear dictionary of some texts, but if it is a problem, I might have to think more how to go about this.

*What I'd really like to see is an interlinear text for an agglutinative language, or something more complex than Greek and Hebrew and Chinese. If you have any examples of that, please comment so I can see and learn. In those cases, I wonder if they would require more than 1-3 words to define their terms, or how it would even look.*

Comment: You can't translate using words. You have to know a language. "More complex than Greek, Hebrew and Chinese?" There is no such thing as a cross-linguistic dictionary. There are monolingual dictionaries and bilingual ones.

Comment: Just because the question is a strange one doesn't mean it needs more clarity or focus. I was unclear what the purpose of linguistic glosses were, hence the question! If I am unclear in my head, that is the whole point of asking! As such I'm unsure the reason for the downvotes, it was a genuine confusion I was wondering about. Also, there is going to be a cross-linguistic dictionary one way or another :]

Comment: Salish dictionaries have to give rather thorough glosses since all Salishan languages are polysynthetic and have lots of lexical suffixes and root classes. The one I'm most familiar with is Bates, Hess, and Hilbert's _Lushootseed Dictionary_. Ken Hill's dictionary of Hopi (if you can find it) is another gem of the genre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a prose definition should really be counted as a proper definition.

A one word gloss is *not* a definition. Glosses are intended to give *a* basic sense of the word where space is tight (as in an interlinear), but they are often mechanically generated (meaning every occurrence is given the same gloss despite potentially very different contextual meanings) and cannot be trusted to give the right sense. Glossing with a single word is a purpose that is *only* useful for interlinears; sticking to single word translations should never be a goal at other times.

The "More deeply" section is not even *trying* to define the word, it is just listing all the ways the word was translated in one translation the Bible. If a resource only does your #2 then *it is not a dictionary* and should not be marketed as one.

What distinguishes dictionaries from each other is how much detail they give in their prose definitions. Do they assume a lot from their readers, or do they explain in more detail? And do they explain the numerous sub-senses of a word, or only the most common? Do they explain not only the denotations of a word, but also its connotations? Some detailed dictionaries (as is common in Biblical studies) arguably say too much, and make it appear as though the various connotations of a word mean that it has more senses than it actually does.

> Is it fair to say that these 3 layers can be used to effectively teach someone the meaning of a new term over time? Start with the basic 1-word to give a hint, which doesn't corrupt. Then after some time, go to many words to paint a blended view of the term, more subtle. Then only when necessary, dig into the details of the term with a prose definition.

No, that would be disastrous. Start with a simple prose definition of the most common sense. Perhaps give prose definitions for the top two senses if they're of similar frequency. Then explain more sub-senses as the student comes across them.

> My go to example currently is "dharma", mapped to "morality". Technically dharma is much more subtle and complex than just saying "morality", but morality gets you more than 50% of the way there to understanding, so it seems like an alright gloss.

If you need to gloss such a complex word, just transliterate it. It is better to leave key terms untranslated in an interlinear than to mislead with a poor gloss. Don't think you can solve what thousands of religious scholars have judged to be an impossible task:

> Dharma is a concept of central importance in Indian philosophy and religion. It has multiple meanings in Hinduism, Buddhism, Sikhism and Jainism. It is difficult to provide a single concise definition for dharma, as the word has a long and varied history and straddles a complex set of meanings and interpretations. There is no equivalent single-word synonym for dharma in western languages.
>
> There have been numerous, conflicting attempts to translate ancient Sanskrit literature with the word dharma into German, English and French. The concept, claims Paul Horsch, has caused exceptional difficulties for modern commentators and translators. For example, while Grassmann's translation of Rig-Veda identifies seven different meanings of dharma, Karl Friedrich Geldner in his translation of the Rig-Veda employs 20 different translations for dharma, including meanings such as "law", "order", "duty", "custom", "quality", and "model", among others. However, the word dharma has become a widely accepted loanword in English, and is included in all modern unabridged English dictionaries.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dharma#Definition)

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of interlinear glosses is not to teach you the definitions of words, but to show you how the grammar works: the syntax and morphology that binds those units together. This requires a very short translation of each unit, to avoid occluding the grammar it's trying to illustrate.

> But how accurate are those definitions? Does it only give you a partial glimpse of the meaning? Is it sufficient, or at least does it serve as a good entry point for understanding?

It's sufficient to demonstrate the grammar. It's not sufficient to show you the real meaning of the word.

Answer (score -1):

Your question actually goes deeper than what you literally ask, the fundamental question is "How trustworthy is linguistic data?". As such, it is at least superficially an opinion question, but it is still a good question, but also a dangerous one because it brings into question the foundations of this science. You may know, for example, that there is no actual science underlying fingerprints as forensic evidence yet it is used in court all the time.

The answer, really, is "the data is as reliable as the source", which could range from "very reliable" vs. "useless". What you would want to know is, on what basis (using what method) was this datum created? As for interlinear glossing, some obvious factors to consider are the fluency of the author in the language and, since this is a translation task, the fluency of the author in the glossing language. Interlinear glosses are a very specialized form of translation, where (at least in terms of selecting the "correct" lexical) you can only hint at the meaning of the word, because you have limited space. When a language has names for 18 kinds of ant and one of those words appears in a text, you don't use the technical Latin name, you use some shorter word like "ant", then the reader has to find a decent dictionary to look up exactly what kind of any that is.

Here are some examples of [Greenlandic texts](https://sites.google.com/view/maria-bittner/kalaallisut) from a (the) leading scholar in Greenlandic.